# php: use cookies only does't work

Tags: php, session-cookies

I change the settings by `ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", "1");` and ini_get returns the right value.
But it seems to make no difference, the sessionID is still added to the URLs on the page.

What could be wrong?

php version is 4.4.9

edit:
Adding the line

```
ini_set ('url_rewriter.tags', '');
```

before `session_start();` solved it!

Thanks guys!

Comment: What about the *session.use\_trans\_sid* option?

Comment: It's turned on, no difference.

Comment: Is the session already active? You should check `session.auto_start`-ini-setting too.

Comment: @jack: It should rather be disabled.

Comment: session.auto_start is 0.
My script starts with:
header(content type...)
ini_set(session use only cookies)
ini_set(session use trans id)
session_name(...)
session_start()

Comment: You add the session id at the end of every link including the session name, right? If you're session name is 'MYSESSION', are you appending `?MYSESSION=<?php echo session_id();?>` instead of `PHPSESSID=...`?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://es.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php, in your php version, `session.use_trans_sid` could be changed at `PHP_INI_PERDIR`. According to http://es.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php, `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, you may change values only at `php.ini`, `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`, but not via `ini_set()`.

So, try to create a `.htaccess` file in the root of your PHP application with this line(if you are using apache):

```
php_value session.use_trans_sid On
```

BTW, consider upgrading to a newer version of PHP. PHP 4.x has been abandoned (not getting security updates) for a while now.

Comment: use_trans_id is turned on by default.

Comment: (It's a shared host, we had many conflicts with the company urging them to update. ;) )

Comment: Again, *session.use\_trans\_sid* should be disabled.

Comment: Why should be disabled? If it's disabled php won't follow sessions by url parameters, right?